# Change default "Always on top" setting for a specific application

Tags: gnome, window, display-manager, layout

My password manager has "always on top" activated every time I start it. I find myself manually unticking it every time. I would like to change its default to the usual one. How can I do it? [How to start an app with "Always On Top" set?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7377/how-to-start-an-app-with-always-on-top-set) didn't work for me.

22.04.3 here.

Comment: I'll suggest applying all security fixes to your system asap, as if your provided details are correct, you've not been applying them since the very beginning of 2023.  If you refer to https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/02/24/ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-released/ you'll note 22.04.2 was early 2023 & installed systems upgraded **before** that date, with upgraded systems now currently reporting as [22.04.3](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/).

Comment: I'm fully updated already, I made a silly typo before. Fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, the linux desktop [gives little control](https://askubuntu.com/a/1322526/558158) to the user about the way application windows should be created. If your application does not expose an option not to launch "always on top", there is little you can do.

On desktops running Xorg, devilspie can be used to automatically set a window not on top. devilspie, however, does not work on Wayland, which the standard Ubuntu desktop uses by default.